# Apache2 can't see files or folders

Tags: 14.04, lamp

I installed apache2 using this command `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` but now when I start it by typing `localhost` in browser I only see message `Index of /` and there is no any files or folders.

Tried to create `index.html` and `index.php` but I got same results.
Is there any fix for this?

Comment: Where did you create these files? (typically it's in `/var/www/`) And, what are the permissions of these files? (Who is owner, group, and which access modes) What is the content of your `/var/log/apache2/error.log` file?

Comment: I created files in /var/www/, I have www-data group and I added my user to this group. This is error log of apache2: http://pastebin.com/gB2zc02g. And all permissions are set to read/write/execute for every file and folder.

Comment: Hmm, it seems apache was looking for folder html inside /var/www/. After I created this folder I could see all folders inside html folder. That's not how I used too. How can I change the root directory so I don't need to use html directory.

Comment: You can modify the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` file, (~ line 14) -> change the `<Directory>`.